# how to changing the border of li with li:hover in internet explorer

Tags: css

Im having problems getting some css to work in internet explorer- works fine in chrome but when i try it in ie-

```
.Menu li:hover {
    border-bottom:10px solid #80B1DD !important;
}
```

i dont have any border on it to start with- any workarounds?

Comment: What version of IE? Does your page have a doctype declaration?

Comment: This rule seems correct in this context.  You may need to append more HTML/CSS for us to better judge the problem.

Comment: I've tried on IE7 and it works [link](http://jsfiddle.net/FP2Jz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support ie6 i used jquery-

```
$(function(){
       $(".sub_menu  li:last-child").css("border-right","none !important")
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

IE6 doesn't support the hover pseudo-class on any element other then the anchor <a href=""></a>  I think this is also true of some older firefox browsers as well like FF2 or maybe even FF3.  The way to handle that is either to wrap your <li> with the <a></a> which will make visual studios complain but does work and renders properly. However, it's not best practice to code like that.

```
.Menu a:hover li {
   border-bottom:10px solid #80B1DD;
}
```

Comment: All versions of Firefox including Phoenix and Firebird (pre-1.0) have full support for `:hover`. If there were any bugs, those were minor edge cases.